# problem with contour,sty with XeLaTeX

Tags: rendering, contour

My codes are follow:

```
\documentclass[]{book}
\RequirePackage[cmyk]{xcolor}%
\RequirePackage[outline]{contour}%
\begin{document}

\newcommand*{\outline}[1]{\color{white}\contour{black}{\Huge#1}}%

\outline{5}

\end{document}
```

If I use the `PDFLaTeX`, then the output display nicely:

[image]

But If I use `XeLaTeX`, then the output affected and it was displayed so lightly as:

[image]

I'm in need of using `XeLaTeX` ony, please suggest...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With pdftex you are using Type1 Computer Modern, and with XeLaTeX you are using OpenType Latin Modern.  The outline generated from the latter does seem rather thin (I think because dvipdfmx isn't understanding the literal postscript intended fori dvips) , but I don't think the package has any documented options to configure that.

If you switch to copy mode however you can have more control (although outline mode is normally to be preferred)

I get

[image]

from

```
\documentclass[]{book}
\RequirePackage[cmyk]{xcolor}%
\RequirePackage[copies]{contour}%
\begin{document}

\contourlength{1pt}

\newcommand*{\outline}[1]{\color{white}\contour{black}{\Huge#1}}%

\outline{5}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Sir @David; much thanks for your quick solution....It's working like a champ...

Answer (score 3):

You can use `bidicontour` package for xelatex to get outline mode. Load it before `bidi` package which defines some internal code for RTL output (which is not actually used here, so does nothing).

Use command `\bidicontour`.

[image: 567]

MWE

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[cmyk]{xcolor}%
\usepackage[outline]{bidicontour}%
\usepackage{bidi}%
\begin{document}

\newcommand*{\outline}[1]{\color{white}\bidicontour{black}{\Huge#1}}%

\outline{567abc}

\end{document}
```

From the documentation:

"The bidicontour package is a re-implementation of contour package adding bidi
support; it also adds support for xdvipdfmx driver when you use outline option
of the package."

"All the commands of contour package are prefixed with bidi in bidicontour
package; for instance instead using \contour command; you will need to use
\bidicontour command."

Comment: Perfect... thanks...

Answer (score 2):

contour is missing a driver for xetex, but basically you only need the pdftex version but with the right special:

```
\RequirePackage[cmyk]{xcolor}%
\RequirePackage[outline]{contour}%
\makeatletter
\renewcommand*\@contour@outline[2]{%
  \begingroup
    \setlength\con@length{2\con@length}%
    \setlength\con@length{0.99626400996\con@length}%
    \color{#1}%
    \con@coloroff
    \special{pdf:literal %
      q
      1 j
      1 J
      1 Tr
      \strip@pt\con@length\space w
    }%
    \rlap{#2}%
    \special{pdf:literal %
      Q
    }%
  \endgroup
  \mbox{#2}%
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\makeatletter\show\@contour@outline
\newcommand*{\outline}[1]{\color{white}\contour{black}{\Huge#1}}%

\outline{5}

\end{document}
```

[image]